# Solve an exact Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $x^3y^2dx+x^2y^3dy=0$ is not exact.

But we can find an integration factor such that $(Mx^3y^2)dx+(Mx^2y^3)dy=0$

Consider that we can have $M=M(x)$ or $M=M(y)$ or $M=M(z)$ where $z=xy$ (actually many more but this should be worth pursuing), The latter should give a solution but I cannot seem to get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide both sides by $x^2y^2$:

$$x dx + y dy = 0 \implies x^2+y^2=C$$

or the solution $xy = 0$ we lost from the division.

Answer (score 1):

After some scribbling here is a longer but more explanatory way of getting to why we should be Dividing by $x^2y^2$

Lets start by assuming $M=M(z)$ where $z=xy$

Note the following by chain rule(since $z=xy$):$$\frac{∂M(z)}{∂x}=\frac{dM}{dz}\frac{∂(xy)}{∂x}=y\frac{dM}{dz}$$
and
$$\frac{∂M(z)}{∂y}=\frac{dM}{dz}\frac{∂(xy)}{∂y}=x\frac{dM}{dz}$$
Then if the original question was in the form $AM(z)dx+BM(z)dy=0$ then we have by product rule:
$$\frac{∂(AM(z))}{∂y} = x^2z^2\frac{dM}{dz}+M(z)2zx^2$$
$$\frac{∂(BM(z))}{∂x} = y^2z^2\frac{dM}{dz}+M(z)2zy^2$$

Then, to fulfill the exactness we have to equate $\frac{∂(AM(z))}{∂y} = \frac{∂(BM(z))}{∂x}$

After simplifying this yields the following simple ODE: $\frac{dM}{dz}=\frac{2M}{z}$

From this we get $M(z)=z^{-2} = \dfrac{1}{(xy)^2}$